# Bootstrap Flex - Prevent Child Items from Stretching Container

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I'm trying to establish a layout where everything can be viewed without scrolling. Any panels that needs more space should be scrollable. In the example below, instead of main-left being stretched, I would like it so that the contents of main-left is srollable and not stretch the entire row.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
$("#main-left").append("<div>" + i + "</div>");
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

#main {
  background-color: cyan;
  min-height: 100vh;
}


#main-right {
  background-color: red;
}

#main-left {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column" id="main">
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <d class="navbar-brand">Header</d>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="row d-flex flex-grow-1 " id="main-row">
    <div class="col-5 d-flex flex-column" id="main-left">
      
    </div>
    <div class="col-2" id="main-center">

    </div>
    <div class="col-5" id="main-right">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for an element to scroll, it must:

- Have an explicit height
- Have enough content to overflow that explicit height
- Have `overflow: auto` or `scroll` declared

The following CSS rule will target all direct children of your `#main-row` and prevent them from stretching your container, allowing scroll:

```css
#main-row > * {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
  $("#main-left").append("<div>" + i + "</div>");
}
```

```css
#main {
  background-color: cyan;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#main-row>* {
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}

#main-right {
  background-color: red;
}

#main-left {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column" id="main">
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <d class="navbar-brand">Header</d>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="row d-flex flex-grow-1 " id="main-row">
    <div class="col-5 d-flex flex-column" id="main-left">
      left
    </div>
    <div class="col-2" id="main-center">
      center
    </div>
    <div class="col-5" id="main-right">
      right
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, I was afraid of that. My issue with this is that the left container does not fully display the contents now. I was hoping there would be a dynamic way to set it.

Comment: @ghost013 You'll have to be much more specific in what you want

Comment: Sorry, to clarify. If you look at the left container, the contents are cut off. I was hoping for a way for the panes to dynamically fill out the height of the window, but not stretch based on its content.

Comment: @ghost013 Don't think words are helping here. Maybe draw up an image, add it to your question, and I'll edit my answer tomorrow

Comment: Maybe, the code snippet is displaying something different for both of us? For me, when on main-left, I can't see anything past 27 because the pane's height is the same as the overall container. On another note, I always try not to hardcode sizes since I would like the panels be scalable, but it seems it might not be possible?